# python split to train/test/val using GroupShuffleSplit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, cross-validation

I have a dataset that I want to split to train (60%) test (20%) and val (20%) using GroupShuffleSplit.
Is it possible to use it for 3 types folds instead of only 2 (train/test)?

If not - what is the best way to implement it?
The code should be something like:

```
gss = GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=6, train_size=.6, random_state=42)
for train_index, test_index, valid_index in gss.split(X = x, y = y, groups=groups):
    ....
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Just make it two times:

```
gs_1 = GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, train_size=.8, random_state=42)
train_test_ix, val_ix = next(gs_1.split(X, y, groups=X_new.group))
X_train_test = X.loc[train_test_ix]
X_val = X.loc[val_ix]
y_train_test = y.loc[train_test_ix]
y_val = y.loc[val_ix]
```

Reset index (it didn't work for me without index reset)

```
X_train_test = X_train_test.reset_index(drop=True)
y_train_test = y_train_test.reset_index(drop=True)
gs_2 = GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, train_size=.75, random_state=42)
train_ix, test_ix = next(gs_2.split(X_train_test, y_train_test, groups=X_train_test.group))
X_train = X_train_test.loc[train_ix]
X_test = X_train_test.loc[test_ix]
y_train = y.loc[train_ix]
y_test = y.loc[test_ix]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `train_test_split` twice to make 60-20-20 splits.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25)
```

Comment: Thanks but it is possible to do it in a for loop with GroupShuffleSplit?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about `GroupShuffleSplit`

Comment: @Adrash Wase and how would you wrap it in a for loop?